# Integrate $\int \frac{4x^5-7x^4+8x^3-2x^2+4x-7}{x^2(x^2+1)^2}dx$

Tags: integration

$\displaystyle\int \frac{4x^5-7x^4+8x^3-2x^2+4x-7}{x^2(x^2+1)^2}dx$

I attempted but in vain.

$\displaystyle\int \frac{4x^5-7x^4+8x^3-2x^2+4x-7}{x^2(x^2+1)^2}dx=\int \frac{4x(x^4+1)}{x^2(x^2+1)^2}-7\frac{(x^4+1)}{x^2(x^2+1)^2}+2\frac{x^2(4x-1)}{x^2(x^2+1)^2}dx$

I got stuck. Please help....

Comment: Partial fractions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By partial fractions decomposition we have $$\int\left(\frac{12}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}}-\frac{7}{x^{2}}+\frac{4}{x}\right)dx
 $$ now for the first integral we can use the substitution $x=\tan\left(u\right)
 $ to get $$12\int\frac{dx}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}}=12\int\cos^{2}\left(u\right)du=6\int\cos\left(2u\right)du+6u=3\sin\left(2u\right)+6u+C_{1}
 $$ for the second $$-7\int\frac{1}{x^{2}}dx=\frac{7}{x}+C_{2}
 $$ and $$4\int\frac{1}{x}dx=4\log\left(x\right)+C_{3}
 $$ so if we substitute back we have $$3\sin\left(2\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)+6\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)+\frac{7}{x}+4\log\left(x\right)+C.
 $$

Comment: True but in this case it's very useful because we get a simple form of the integral.

Comment: Well done! Just a note: $3\sin(2\tan^{-1}(x))$ can be simplified to $6x/(1+x^2)$.